# Group list elements by parent Id, then order by another field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So I have a list of elements such as this:

```
public class Schedule
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public int Prompt {get; set;}
   public int Hierarchy {get;set;}
   public string? ParentId {get;set;
   public virtual ICollection<Schedule> Children {get;set;}
}
```

Any element can have n Children, and their Children more children, I'm trying to display the data as a tree, but I also want to order by the Prompt field; this field is a incremental index, so all the parents do not have the same value, but when you go into their children, this index returns to value = 1 and so on.

The Hierarchy field is to know how deep the child is in the tree

Comment: Can you show how you are attempting to retrieve this data? So we have a starting point

Comment: If you want to group by ParentId anyways, you'll have all children of a specific parent in a group anyways, so you might as well sort the groups and return all values (.SelectMany()).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a recursive function that traverses the tree and sorts all the children.

```
private IEnumerable<Schedule> Sort(IEnumerable<Schedule> schedules)
{
    var sorted = schedules.OrderBy(s => s.Prompt);

    foreach (var schedule in sorted.Where(s => s.Children != null && s.Children.Any()))
    {
        schedule.Children = Sort(schedule.Children).ToList();
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

Which you can call on the original list:

```
var schedules = new List<Schedule>(); // get schedules from somewhere
var sorted = Sort(schedules);
```